# Python3.10, Text Doesn't Show On Pygame Window

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.10

I am trying to make a app where you enter in the minute value then a timer pops up on a window. The timer isnt appearing. I am using python 3.10. I'm new to python so please if you can fix it, please include the source code.

```
import pygame
import time
import sys

pygame.init()

q = True
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 35)

def countdown(t):
    t *= 60
    while t:
        min, sec = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(min, sec)
#
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pygame.display.set_caption('PyTimerTwo,  By: ChanceMeteor515')
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        text = str(timer)
        label = myFont.render(text, 1, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(label, (WIDTH - 200, HEIGHT - 40))
#
    print("\nTime's Up")
    time.sleep(5400)

t = input("Enter Time In Minutes:")
countdown(int(t))

while q:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_h:
                pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                sys.exit()

    clock.tick(120)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `countdown` function, you forgot to update the display with `pygame.display.update()` and you also forgot to add an event loop, so you won't be able to close the window. If you add these, the timer will appear.

## Modified Code:

```
import pygame
import time
import sys

pygame.init()

q = True
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 35)

def countdown(t):
    t *= 60
    while t:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        min, sec = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(min, sec)
#
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pygame.display.set_caption('PyTimerTwo,  By: ChanceMeteor515')
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        text = str(timer)
        label = myFont.render(text, True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(label, (WIDTH - 200, HEIGHT - 40))

        pygame.display.update()
#
    print("\nTime's Up")
    time.sleep(5400)

t = input("Enter Time In Minutes:")
countdown(int(t))

while q:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_h:
                pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                sys.exit()

    clock.tick(120)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: This code adds the text but it doesnt count down. How do you make it countdown?

Comment: @ChanceMeteor515 In your question, you asked how to make the text appear, but you didn’t mention anything about the countdown. Maybe try to implement it and then if you need help ask another question.